# Which Visual Studio Plugins have caused you more pain? Killed your IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in

I recently had to reinstall VS 2008 as it kept crashing (I suspect due to some plugin). I was just wondering if there are any "Use at your own risk" visual studio plugins. Has anyone seen a dialog box popup asking for error details called JIRA when using Visual Studio?? My IDE started crashing once I started getting those dialogs.

This is not to create a hate list but a precautionary list of plugins that can screw up your unsaved work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powercommands caused VS2008 to crash when I loaded XAML files. I blogged about it [here](http://irwinj.blogspot.com). There is a fix and it is a handy little plugin

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that happen with **Resharper** from JetBrains.  Usually a restart of the IDE takes care of it. Its been happening less in later version.

Comment: +1 JetBrains use JIRA for issue tracking I believe, I use resharper and love it, but i do also have a JIRA userid. So that could be saying something! (note: i've no association with Jetbrains just a [happy] user)

Comment: I love the Resharper too - having that problem is not a deal breaker at all

Comment: If it would make that JIRA dialog go away I will get that user Id too